# Typescript: infer union type from module/object values

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to accomplish something analogous to `keyof typeof myModule` in typescript. Rather than a union of key strings, however, I'm looking for a union of the value types.

I have a module that exports a growing number of items -

myModule.ts:

```ts
export const Thing1;
export const Thing2;
export const Thing3;
// ... many more things!
```

This module is imported elsewhere, and I want to construct a union type that is `Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | ...`, but without doing so manually.

anotherModule.ts:

```ts
import * as things from './myModule';

type AnyThingKey = keyof typeof things;

function useThings(thing: /* AnyThing - this is where/how I'd use the union type */) {
    // ... do things ...
}
```

Is there an accepted way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close to the solution.

Your `anotherModule.ts` should probably look like this:

```
import * as things from './myModule';

type AnyThingKey = typeof things[keyof typeof things];

function useThings(thing: AnyThingKey) {
  // ... do things ...
}

useThings("Thing1"); // OK
useThings("foo");    // compiler error
```